# SharePoint 2013 search in List

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, search

I'm quite new to SharePoint and hope this is the right place to ask. A through web search could not give me or my colleagues the answer.

We made a new list with information about employees and when they made certain certificates. The users started using the list and searching for people, to find out if they are allowed to do certain things which are only allowed due to the certifications.
When typing only one part of the name, let's say "Smi" out of "Smith" you need to use the Asterisk "*" to get search results.
The problem is with some names, for example "Zimmermann" the search gets results when you only search for "mann". Another Example would be "Eck" instead of "Eckes". In this case "Eck" will already lead to the correct search results.

Can someone please lead me to the right direction why the search only works like this sometimes? Our users are annoyed that sometimes they need to use the Asterisk, sometimes not.

We are a bit restricted, as such we do not have access to CA / Powershell / Designer.

Sorry for my kinda broken englisch.

Comment: You should always need the asterix, given that the "partial" words are not present somewhere in the documents themselves or in another metadata

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your input! I took a look into the list. In the entry for "Zimmermann" there is no cell with the information "mann". This stays true for the other entrys and cells. We have not set any metadata.

Comment: Yes ,agree with Robert ,  you should always use prefix matching , for "Zimmermann" , you need pay attention to the user profile or user information list .

Answer (score 0):

It's just the way the javascript handles the info.

From what i've noticed, it's the second word after a space that causes confusion.

so Bo in Bob will find correctly, but his last name Joe
when you search Jo it won't find it.

There is a work around for this, which can be done by manipulating the search properties with javascript. If you do some browsing on stackoverflow, I know i've read about this and saw a sample code you can use.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of websites that helped me understand how Search works. Text searches go from left to right so you can only add an wild card "*" at the end of some text. Search wont return results from characters in the middle of a word.

Keyword Query Language (KQL) syntax reference: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference

2 ways to search for files in SharePoint - Blog SharePointMaven: 
https://sharepointmaven.com/2-ways-to-search-for-files-in-sharepoint/

icanSharePoint - blog search infographic: 
http://icansharepoint.com/infographic-search-sharepoint/